# Canvas.drawText add extra letter space for small text size (1px)

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview

I draw some short texts using Canvas.drawText() on scaled canvas. Texts has different sizes, dynamically calculated. Some texts have very small sizes (1-2px). The problem is that if text size less than ~2px canvas adds extra space between characters.

Examples:
text size 4px, normal letter space:
[image: 4px]

text size 1px, added extra letter space:
[image: 1px]

Code example:

```
canvas.save()
canvas.scale(8f, 8f)
paint.textSize = 1f
canvas.drawText("66", x, y, paint)        
canvas.restore()
```

Answer (score 3):

I found solution (Kotlin):

```
paint.isLinearText = true
paint.isSubpixelText = true
```